# Android Fragment Tutorial's code not clear

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm brushing up on my Fragments knowledge following the [official tutorial from android developers website](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html); there is a statement into the demo code that doesn't sound clear to me

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
if (index == 0) {
    ft.replace(R.id.details, details);
} else {
    ft.replace(R.id.a_item, details);
}
```

I think I can understand the logic behind the code, but can't figure out where is that item with id = a_item; it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere and obviously the demo app doesn't work.

Can you help me to better understand that piece of code? Thanks in advance

Comment: I cant explain that without seeing the whole thing but I can give you a guess as to what I think its getting at. General speaking fragments you have two xml files 1 in the layout and 1 in the layout-large folder and are bothed named the same. My guess would be is that index value somehow determines where your in tablet mode or phone mode and based upon that replceas those two fragments. I'd imaginet htat the a_item fragment is declared somewhere n the layout-large version of the xml file. Lmk if I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes ksudu94, you're right, but the a_item element ins't declared anywhere into the code; I guess the developers forgot to insert a layout file into the tutorial

Answer (score 0):

- `R.id.details` refers to a `ViewGroup` inside which you would like to insert a fragment (or replace one).
- `details` refers to the instance of the fragment that should be inserted/replaced in the `ViewGroup`

Notes:

- Don't forget to call `transaction.commit()` to actually
- This will not work with fragment inserted directly in XML using the fragment tag. You can only replace a fragment that has been inserted from your Java code.

Comment: The problem is with the a_item element, it doesn't seem to be declared anywhere